# and custom post_types to custom menu

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, add-menu-page

managed to create a custom menu area in the admin but now want to place 2 post types to it.

They already exist - questions & answers, but can't find a way to put their menu links into the custom menu.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages');

function mt_add_pages() {

    add_menu_page(__('Competition','comp'), __('Competition','comp'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', 'test_func', '', 5 );
    add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Answers','comp-answers'),  __('Answers','comp-answers'), 'manage_options', 'sub-page', 'test_func2');

}

function test_func(){
    echo 1; // question post_type links
}

function test_func2(){
    echo 2; // answer post_type links
}
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up defining it in the register_post_type function...

```
'show_in_menu' => 'mt-top-level-handle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the action after the function like this:

```
function mt_add_pages() {
    // Add theme options page to the addmin menu
    add_menu_page(__('Competition','comp'), __('Competition','comp'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', 'test_func', '', 5 );
    add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Answers','comp-answers'),  __('Answers','comp-answers'), 'manage_options', 'sub-page', 'test_func2');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages' );
```